# Expression Language bean property evaluation order

Tags: jsf, xpages, el

Given a managed bean (MyBean) which extends an abstract class (AbstractMapModel) which is essentially a wrapper for a Map:

The AbstractMapModel class includes a getValue(Object key) method.

The MyBean class includes a getName() method.

The XPage has a value which evaluates to #{MyBean.name}.

I'm finding that it invokes MyBean.getValue("Name") and ignores MyBean.getName(). My question is, is this correct operation?

Logically, it seems like it should try the more specific getName() before trying the generalized getValue("Name"). Doing some research, it appears that if getValue() returns null, it is supposed to look for a specific getter, which even if I find the logic dubious, at least would get correct end result. However, neither is happening.

I've solved the problem with the following code:

```
public Object getValue(final Object key) {
    /* Following code added to check for specific getter before performing getValues() */
    String propertyName = key.toString();
    propertyName = propertyName.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + propertyName.substring(1);
    Method method = null;
    try {
        method = this.getClass().getMethod("get" + propertyName, new Class[] {});
        if (method != null) {
            return method.invoke(this);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Do nothing
    }
    try {
        method = this.getClass().getMethod("is" + propertyName, new Class[] {});
        if (method != null) {
            return method.invoke(this);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    /* --------------------------------------------- */
    return getValues().get(key);
}
```

It does not seem like this workaround should be necessary, so I'm wondering if I have some fundamental misunderstanding of what is going on. Alternately, is there some better way I ought to be doing this?

Comment: I've not seen it in a long time, but Tim Tripcony did a video about this for NotesIn9 and talked about this exact issue if I remember correctly.  Basically whatever Tim suggested is the best solution.

Comment: What I'm doing is derived from Tim's work. I haven't reviewed that NI9 in some time, and I suppose I just mis-remembered how this worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As much as it'd be often useful, EL doesn't follow a "fallback" strategy like that. Instead, it has a set of interfaces that it cycles through - `Map`, `DataObject`, etc. (I don't remember the specific order) - and, if the object matches one of those, it will use that route exclusively. What you did there, with reflection, is the same strategy I've used to get that behavior.

Comment: Hypothetically, you could register a new handler at the start of the list that would take any object and do that "fallback" ordering on it, but that would probably be too hacky to be worth it.

Comment: I try to code for minimal hackiness, so I think I'll just stick with this method. Is there a reason not to do it this way, like poor performance or something? I'm trying to decide if that belongs in the abstract class, or if I should override that behavior on a case-by-case basis. I could override my getValue to look for specific keys and then return the method rather than looking up the value from the map. But that code would look really ugly.

Comment: There's not any huge reason to worry about performance on reflection until it turns into an actual problem - while reflection is "slow" compared to, say, integer tests, it's very fast compared to anything database-related. I've been using this route for a while and haven't had to think twice about it. If it _does_ prove to be too slow, your "check for specific keys" route is the way to go - that's what IBM's objects like DominoViewEntry do.